# Accessing rexiv2 Metadata As Buffer Rather Than Saving

Tags: rust, metadata, exiv2

Using the Rust crate [rexiv2](https://docs.rs/rexiv2/latest/rexiv2/), I was wondering if there was a method to access the adjusted metadata as a byte array? For example, I understand the workflow to be:

- Load file either from buffer, file path, or APP1 segment
- Adjust metadata
- Save the adjusted metadata to a file on disk

Since it is possible to load the file from a buffer, is there a way to access the adjusted metadata as a buffer?